# dl_iterate_phdr equivalent on Mac

Tags: c, macos

I want to iterate through all loaded shared libraries and get their base addresses as well as their file names. This is basically [`dl_iterate_phdr`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dl_iterate_phdr) on Linux.

But I want to do the same for Mac.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functions documented in the dyld(3) man page (which no longer seem to be online) seem to provide the analogous functionality.

Here's that content:

> ### NAME
>
> ```
>  _dyld_image_count, _dyld_get_image_header, _dyld_get_image_vmaddr_slide,
>  _dyld_get_image_name, _dyld_register_func_for_add_image,
>  _dyld_register_func_for_remove_image, NSVersionOfRunTimeLibrary,
>  NSVersionOfLinkTimeLibrary _NSGetExecutablePath
> ```
>
> ### SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>  #include <mach-o/dyld.h>
>
>  uint32_t
>  _dyld_image_count(void);
>
>  const struct mach_header*
>  _dyld_get_image_header(uint32_t image_index);
>
>  intptr_t
>  _dyld_get_image_vmaddr_slide(uint32_t image_index);
>
>  const char*
>  _dyld_get_image_name(uint32_t image_index);
>
>  void
>  _dyld_register_func_for_add_image(void (*func)(const struct mach_header* mh, intptr_t vmaddr_slide));
>
>  void
>  _dyld_register_func_for_remove_image(void (*func)(const struct mach_header* mh, intptr_t vmaddr_slide));
>
>  int32_t
>  NSVersionOfRunTimeLibrary(const char* libraryName);
>
>  int32_t
>  NSVersionOfLinkTimeLibrary(const char* libraryName);
>
>  int
>  _NSGetExecutablePath(char* buf, uint32_t* bufsize);
> ```
>
> ### DESCRIPTION
>
> These routines provide additional introspection of dyld beyond that
>   provided by `dlopen()` and `dladdr()`
>
> `_dyld_image_count()` returns the current number of images mapped in
>   by dyld. Note that using this count to iterate all images is not
>   thread safe, because another thread may be adding or removing images
>   during the iteration.
>
> `_dyld_get_image_header()` returns a pointer to the mach header of the
>   image indexed by image_index.  If `image_index` is out of range, NULL
>   is returned.
>
> `_dyld_get_image_vmaddr_slide()` returns the virtural memory address
>   slide amount of the image indexed by `image_index`. If `image_index`
>   is out of range zero is returned.
>
> `_dyld_get_image_name()` returns the name of the image indexed by
>   `image_index`. The C-string continues to be owned by dyld and should
>   not deleted.  If `image_index` is out of range NULL is returned.
>
> `_dyld_register_func_for_add_image()` registers the specified function
>   to be called when a new image is added (a bundle or a dynamic shared
>   library) to the program.  When this function is first registered it is
>   called for once for each image that is currently part of the process.
>
> `_dyld_register_func_for_remove_image()` registers the specified
>   function to be called when an image is removed (a bundle or a dynamic
>   shared library) from the process.
>
> `NSVersionOfRunTimeLibrary()` returns the current_version number of
>   the currently loaded dylib specifed by the libraryName.  The
>   libraryName parameter would be "bar" for /path/libbar.3.dylib and
>   "Foo" for /path/Foo.framework/Versions/A/Foo.  This function returns
>   -1 if no such library is loaded.
>
> `NSVersionOfLinkTimeLibrary()` returns the current_version number that
>   the main executable was linked against at build time.  The libraryName
>   parameter would be "bar" for /path/libbar.3.dylib and "Foo" for
>   /path/Foo.framework/Versions/A/Foo.  This function returns -1 if the
>   main executable did not link against the specified library.
>
> `_NSGetExecutablePath()` copies the path of the main executable into
>   the buffer `buf`.  The `bufsize` parameter should initially be the
>   size of the buffer.  This function returns 0 if the path was
>   successfully copied, and
>   * `bufsize` is left unchanged.  It returns -1 if the buffer is not large enough, and * `bufsize` is set to the size required.  Note that
>   `_NSGetExecutablePath()` will return "a path" to the executable not a
>   "real path" to the executable.  That is, the path may be a symbolic
>   link and not the real file. With deep directories the total bufsize
>   needed could be more than `MAXPATHLEN`.

Answer (score 4):

Just for completion:

The input is any pointer to some static content (e.g. a function) and the goal was to find the library and its section.

I implemented this [here](https://github.com/albertz/openlierox/blob/0.59/src/common/Debug_extended_backtrace.cpp) in the `ptr_is_in_exe` function:

```
static bool
ptr_is_in_exe(const void *ptr, const struct mach_header *& header, intptr_t& offset, uintptr_t& vmaddr, std::string& image_name)
{
    uint32_t i, count = _dyld_image_count();

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        header = _dyld_get_image_header(i);
        offset = _dyld_get_image_vmaddr_slide(i);

        uint32_t j = 0;
        struct load_command* cmd = (struct load_command*)((char *)header + sizeof(struct mach_header));
        if(header->magic == MH_MAGIC_64)
            cmd = (struct load_command*)((char *)header + sizeof(struct mach_header_64));

        while (j < header->ncmds) {
            if (cmd->cmd == LC_SEGMENT) {
                struct segment_command* seg = (struct segment_command*)cmd;
                if (((intptr_t)ptr >= (seg->vmaddr + offset)) && ((intptr_t)ptr < (seg->vmaddr + offset + seg->vmsize))) {
                    vmaddr = seg->vmaddr;
                    image_name = _dyld_get_image_name(i);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if (cmd->cmd == LC_SEGMENT_64) {
                struct segment_command_64* seg = (struct segment_command_64*)cmd;
                if (((uintptr_t)ptr >= (seg->vmaddr + offset)) && ((uintptr_t)ptr < (seg->vmaddr + offset + seg->vmsize))) {
                    vmaddr = seg->vmaddr;
                    image_name = _dyld_get_image_name(i);
                    return true;
                }
            }

            j++;
            cmd = (struct load_command*)((char*)cmd + cmd->cmdsize);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: For posterity, given the goals you mentioned in this answer (but not your question), it's much simpler to use `dladdr()`.