# Getting the runtime path of a shared object from within itself

Tags: c, linux, windows, macos, shared-libraries

Given the following library :

libfoo.{so,dll,dylib}:

```
const char* get_lib_path() {
    return ...;
}
```

built as a shared library (for instance with GCC) :

```
gcc -shared -fPIC foo.cpp -o libfoo.so
```

is there a way to get `get_lib_path()` to return, at runtime, the path where the library resides on the file system, whether on Windows, macOS, Linux ?

The final name of the library is not known : I can't assume a search of the string "libfoo.so" from the list of the loaded libraries.

This must not require the native handle to the dynamically loaded object: I want to know the path from inside my library, and I do not have control over the application that loads it (so I can't get the `dlopen` handle for instance).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find location of loaded shared library, from in that shared library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43409167/find-location-of-loaded-shared-library-from-in-that-shared-library)

Comment: mhh.. I don't know under which name the library will be so I can't use the solution in there.

Comment: You can, just use any address inside the library to identify the module. This would work both for `dl_iterate_phdr` and `/proc/self/maps`.

Comment: how would this work with win32?

Comment: Windows has similar APIs, check e.g. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682621(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: A mechanism can be :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681060/library-path-when-dynamically-loaded

Comment: I have added an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57201397/1005215 which uses `dladdr`

Comment: I wrote a library that uses the /proc/self/maps file to get the file path for any memory address. The 'whereami" function returns the file path to the executable/library containing the caller https://github.com/blackle/whereami

Comment: @BlackleMori I think that the name conflicts a bit with https://github.com/gpakosz/whereami no ?

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier wow! I had no idea this existed! what a wild coincidence that we named it the same thing. It looks like this supports many more platforms than mine. Probably best to use this library than the one I made.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, you can use `GetModuleFilename` or even easier [`GetMappedFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmappedfilenamew).  The latter takes any address inside the library.

Answer (score -4):

I would say no. Technically it does not matter where the library code was loaded from. Once in memory, all that is known are things like the symbols that are being referred to. The original library file is no longer relevant once the code is in memory.

Comment: >  The original library file is no longer relevant once the code is in memory.

In my case it is relevant: I want to ship a library and some data files with it, in the same folder. I want to find the path to the library so that I can find the path to my data files.

Comment: That is not how a shared library should work. You either ship the data in your library, or you put functionality in a library that allows someone to pass a search path.

Comment: On Windows, the original library file is still relevant, because the code in memory is not a copy, it is a memory-mapped file.